# make tuples scala string

Tags: scala, loops, tuples

I have an RDD of Array[String] that looks like this:

```
 mystring= ['thisisastring', 'thisisastring', 'thisisastring', 'thisisastring' ......]
```

I need to make each element, or each line into a Tuple, which combines a fixed number of items together so that they can be passed around as a whole. 
So, essentially, it's like:

```
(1, 'thisisastring')
(2, 'thisisastring')
(3, 'thisisastring')
```

So I think I need to use Tuple2, which is Tuple2[Int, String]. Remind me if I'm wrong.

when I did this: val `vertice = Tuple2(1, mystring)`. 
I realized that I'm just adding int 1 to every line.
So I need a loop iterating through my Array[String], to add 1, 2, and 3, to line 1, line 2 and line 3. 
I thought about using while(count<14900). 
But `val count` is a fixed number, I can't update the value of count each time. 
Do you have a better way to do this?

Comment: Note that `(A, B)` is equivalent to `Tuple2(A, B)`

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: if I do zipwithindex, it will give me a tuple right? bcz i'm gonna add edges and vertices, they need to be tuples

Comment: What I mean is that there is special support for tuples in Scala. Surrounding 2 items, separated by a comma,  in parentheses creates a Tuple2, 3 items makes a Tuple3, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for zipWithIndex.

You don't specify the type you want the resulting RDD to be but
this will give you `RDD[(Int, String)]`:

```
rdd.flatMap(_.zipWithIndex)
```

This will give you `RDD[Array[(Int, String)]`:

```
rdd.map(_.zipWithIndex)
```

Comment: Answering your general comment here as it's asking about zipWithIndex. Yes zip, and zipWithIndex both create Tuple2.

Answer (score 1):

how about using for & yield.

```
for ( i <- 1 to count ) yield Tuple2(i, mystring(i) )
```